# recursive CTE with two child column

Tags: mysql, recursive-query, recursive-cte

basically I have a audit table like the following.

| JOB_NO | DEPENDANT_JOB_NO | DEPENDANT_SUB_JOB_NO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Job_198 | Job_551 | BDP2_Sjob_48 |
| Job_24 | Job_551 | BDP2_Sjob_23 |
| BIL_Job_10 | Job_5 | Sjob_6 |

I need to develop a recursive cte where it should list of like

| JOB_NO | DEPENDANT_JOB_NO | DEPENDANT_SUB_JOB_NO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Job_198 | Job_551 | BDP2_Sjob_48 |
| Job_551 | -- | - |
| BDP2_Sjob_48 | - | - |

This is just for reference for only JOB_198.

I tried the below code but the results are no expected.

```
with recursive rec_cte as (
    select JOB_NO,DEPENDANT_JOB_NO,DEPENDANT_SUB_JOB_NO
    from CTL_TALEND_JOBS_METADATA 
    where JOB_NO ='Job_198'

    union all

    select p.DEPENDANT_JOB_NO,h.DEPENDANT_JOB_NO,h.DEPENDANT_SUB_JOB_NO
    from rec_cte p
    inner join CTL_TALEND_JOBS_METADATA h
        on (h.JOB_NO = p.DEPENDANT_JOB_NO)
),
rec_cte1 as (
    select JOB_NO,DEPENDANT_JOB_NO,DEPENDANT_SUB_JOB_NO
    from CTL_TALEND_JOBS_METADATA 
    where JOB_NO ='Job_198'

    union all

    select p.DEPENDANT_SUB_JOB_NO,h.DEPENDANT_JOB_NO,h.DEPENDANT_SUB_JOB_NO
    from rec_cte1 p
    inner join CTL_TALEND_JOBS_METADATA  h
        on (h.JOB_NO = REPLACE(p.DEPENDANT_SUB_JOB_NO,'BDP2_Sj','J'))
)
select * from rec_cte
union 
select * from rec_cte1;
```

The results of the query ->

```
JOB_NO  DEPENDANT_JOB_NO  DEPENDANT_SUB_JOB_NO
Job_41  Job_19  
Job_41  Job_31  
Job_41  Job_32  
Job_41  Job_37  
Job_19  Job_551            BDP2_Sjob_15
Job_31  Job_13  
Job_32  Job_9   
Job_37  Job_260 
Job_13  Job_551            BDP2_Sjob_8
Job_260 Job_551            BDP2_Sjob_50
Job_551     
Job_9   Job_551            BDP2_Sjob_5
```

I have added the data below.

```
JOB_NO   DEPENDANT_JOB_NO SUB_DEPANDANT_JOB_NO
Job_198 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_48
Job_24  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_23
BIL_Job_10  Job_5   Sjob_6
BIL_Job_106 Job_5   Sjob_40
BIL_Job_109 Job_5   Sjob_39
BIL_Job_11  Job_5   Sjob_3
BIL_Job_12  Job_5   Sjob_7
BIL_Job_13  Job_5   Sjob_8
BIL_Job_14  Job_5   Sjob_10
BIL_Job_15  Job_5   Sjob_11
BIL_Job_16  Job_5   Sjob_9
BIL_Job_169 Job_5   Sjob_45
BIL_Job_18  Job_5   Sjob_20
BIL_Job_188 Job_5   Sjob_46
BIL_Job_19  Job_5   Sjob_15
BIL_Job_20  Job_5   Sjob_16
BIL_Job_21  Job_5   Sjob_19
BIL_Job_22  Job_5   Sjob_17
BIL_Job_23  Job_5   Sjob_18
BIL_Job_236 Job_5   Sjob_49
BIL_Job_26  Job_5   Sjob_13
BIL_Job_260 Job_5   Sjob_50
BIL_Job_27  Job_5   Sjob_12
BIL_Job_29  Job_5   Sjob_14
BIL_Job_373 Job_5   Sjob_53
BIL_Job_49  Job_5   Sjob_24
BIL_Job_50  Job_5   Sjob_26
BIL_Job_502 Job_5   Sjob_54
BIL_Job_505 Job_5   Sjob_55
BIL_Job_506 Job_5   Sjob_56
BIL_Job_508 Job_5   Sjob_57
BIL_Job_52  Job_5   Sjob_29
BIL_Job_53  Job_5   Sjob_30
BIL_Job_7   Job_5   Sjob_22
BIL_Job_72  Job_5   Sjob_32
BIL_Job_73  Job_5   Sjob_31
BIL_Job_76  Job_5   Sjob_34
BIL_Job_8   Job_5   Sjob_1
BIL_Job_80  Job_5   Sjob_36
BIL_Job_82  Job_5   Sjob_35
BIL_Job_9   Job_5   Sjob_5
Job_1       
Job_10  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_6
Job_100 Job_97  
Job_101 Job_98  
Job_102 Job_99  
Job_103 Job_100 
Job_104 Job_101 
Job_105 Job_102 
Job_105 Job_464 
Job_105 Job_462 
Job_106 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_40
Job_107     
Job_108 Job_107 
Job_109 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_39
Job_11  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_3
Job_110 Job_106 
Job_111 Job_543 
Job_111 Job_108 
Job_112 Job_109 
Job_112 Job_45  
Job_114 Job_118 
Job_114 Job_74  
Job_115 Job_56  
Job_115 Job_71  
Job_115 Job_460 
Job_115 Job_461 
Job_116 Job_115 
Job_116 Job_35  
Job_116 Job_36  
Job_116 Job_112 
Job_116 Job_488 
Job_116 Job_515 
Job_116 Job_514 
Job_116 Job_513 
Job_116 Job_574 
Job_117 Job_116 
Job_118 Job_74  
Job_118 Job_64  
Job_119 Job_114 
Job_12  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_7
Job_120 Job_74  
Job_120 Job_36  
Job_120 Job_115 
Job_120 Job_118 
Job_121 Job_44  
Job_121 Job_115 
Job_121 Job_118 
Job_122 Job_115 
Job_122 Job_45  
Job_122 Job_44  
Job_122 Job_36  
Job_122 Job_118 
Job_123 Job_115 
Job_123 Job_43  
Job_123 Job_81  
Job_123 Job_118 
Job_124 Job_120 
Job_124 Job_121 
Job_124 Job_122 
Job_124 Job_123 
Job_125 Job_115 
Job_125 Job_74  
Job_125 Job_44  
Job_125 Job_119 
Job_125 Job_124 
Job_125 Job_118 
Job_126 Job_45  
Job_126 Job_115 
Job_126 Job_36  
Job_126 Job_44  
Job_126 Job_124 
Job_126 Job_118 
Job_127 Job_115 
Job_127 Job_44  
Job_127 Job_124 
Job_127 Job_118 
Job_128 Job_115 
Job_128 Job_44  
Job_128 Job_124 
Job_128 Job_118 
Job_129 Job_125 
Job_129 Job_126 
Job_129 Job_127 
Job_129 Job_128 
Job_13  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_8
Job_130 Job_119 
Job_130 Job_34  
Job_130 Job_124 
Job_130 Job_129 
Job_130 Job_118 
Job_131 Job_115 
Job_131 Job_119 
Job_131 Job_43  
Job_131 Job_124 
Job_131 Job_129 
Job_131 Job_118 
Job_132 Job_44  
Job_132 Job_115 
Job_132 Job_124 
Job_132 Job_129 
Job_132 Job_118 
Job_133 Job_48  
Job_133 Job_115 
Job_133 Job_124 
Job_133 Job_129 
Job_133 Job_118 
Job_134 Job_119 
Job_134 Job_44  
Job_134 Job_115 
Job_134 Job_124 
Job_134 Job_129 
Job_134 Job_118 
Job_135 Job_115 
Job_135 Job_81  
Job_135 Job_124 
Job_135 Job_129 
Job_135 Job_118 
Job_136 Job_115 
Job_136 Job_48  
Job_136 Job_124 
Job_136 Job_129 
Job_136 Job_118 
Job_137 Job_130 
Job_137 Job_131 
Job_137 Job_132 
Job_137 Job_133 
Job_137 Job_134 
Job_137 Job_135 
Job_137 Job_136 
Job_138 Job_119 
Job_138 Job_124 
Job_138 Job_129 
Job_138 Job_137 
Job_138 Job_118 
Job_139 Job_119 
Job_139 Job_115 
Job_139 Job_124 
Job_139 Job_129 
Job_139 Job_137 
Job_139 Job_118 
Job_14  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_10
Job_140 Job_115 
Job_140 Job_119 
Job_140 Job_124 
Job_140 Job_129 
Job_140 Job_137 
Job_140 Job_118 
Job_141 Job_115 
Job_141 Job_119 
Job_141 Job_124 
Job_141 Job_129 
Job_141 Job_137 
Job_141 Job_118 
Job_142 Job_44  
Job_142 Job_115 
Job_142 Job_124 
Job_142 Job_129 
Job_142 Job_137 
Job_142 Job_118 
Job_143 Job_115 
Job_143 Job_119 
Job_143 Job_124 
Job_143 Job_129 
Job_143 Job_137 
Job_143 Job_118 
Job_144 Job_115 
Job_144 Job_119 
Job_144 Job_124 
Job_144 Job_129 
Job_144 Job_137 
Job_144 Job_118 
Job_145 Job_115 
Job_145 Job_81  
Job_145 Job_124 
Job_145 Job_129 
Job_145 Job_137 
Job_145 Job_118 
Job_146 Job_115 
Job_146 Job_48  
Job_146 Job_124 
Job_146 Job_129 
Job_146 Job_137 
Job_146 Job_118 
Job_147 Job_138 
Job_147 Job_139 
Job_147 Job_140 
Job_147 Job_141 
Job_147 Job_142 
Job_147 Job_143 
Job_147 Job_144 
Job_147 Job_145 
Job_147 Job_146 
Job_147 Job_573 
Job_148 Job_115 
Job_148 Job_110 
Job_148 Job_124 
Job_148 Job_129 
Job_148 Job_137 
Job_148 Job_147 
Job_148 Job_118 
Job_149 Job_115 
Job_149 Job_81  
Job_149 Job_124 
Job_149 Job_129 
Job_149 Job_137 
Job_149 Job_147 
Job_15  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_11
Job_150 Job_115 
Job_150 Job_111 
Job_150 Job_124 
Job_150 Job_129 
Job_150 Job_137 
Job_150 Job_147 
Job_151 Job_115 
Job_151 Job_36  
Job_151 Job_74  
Job_151 Job_124 
Job_151 Job_129 
Job_151 Job_137 
Job_151 Job_147 
Job_152 Job_115 
Job_152 Job_40  
Job_152 Job_41  
Job_152 Job_124 
Job_152 Job_129 
Job_152 Job_137 
Job_152 Job_147 
Job_153 Job_148 
Job_153 Job_149 
Job_153 Job_150 
Job_153 Job_151 
Job_153 Job_152 
Job_153 Job_162 
Job_153 Job_197 
Job_154 Job_115 
Job_154 Job_124 
Job_154 Job_129 
Job_154 Job_137 
Job_154 Job_147 
Job_154 Job_153 
Job_155 Job_115 
Job_155 Job_43  
Job_155 Job_124 
Job_155 Job_129 
Job_155 Job_137 
Job_155 Job_147 
Job_155 Job_153 
Job_156 Job_115 
Job_156 Job_44  
Job_156 Job_124 
Job_156 Job_129 
Job_156 Job_137 
Job_156 Job_147 
Job_156 Job_153 
Job_156 Job_118 
Job_156 Job_548 
Job_157 Job_115 
Job_157 Job_112 
Job_157 Job_124 
Job_157 Job_129 
Job_157 Job_137 
Job_157 Job_147 
Job_157 Job_153 
Job_158 Job_115 
Job_158 Job_71  
Job_158 Job_124 
Job_158 Job_129 
Job_158 Job_137 
Job_158 Job_147 
Job_158 Job_153 
Job_159 Job_115 
Job_159 Job_71  
Job_159 Job_36  
Job_159 Job_124 
Job_159 Job_129 
Job_159 Job_137 
Job_159 Job_147 
Job_159 Job_153 
Job_16  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_9
Job_160 Job_115 
Job_160 Job_119 
Job_160 Job_35  
Job_160 Job_124 
Job_160 Job_129 
Job_160 Job_137 
Job_160 Job_147 
Job_160 Job_153 
Job_160 Job_118 
Job_161 Job_154 
Job_161 Job_155 
Job_161 Job_156 
Job_161 Job_157 
Job_161 Job_158 
Job_161 Job_159 
Job_161 Job_160 
Job_162 Job_48  
Job_162 Job_115 
Job_162 Job_124 
Job_162 Job_129 
Job_162 Job_137 
Job_162 Job_147 
Job_164 Job_161 
Job_168 Job_Tealium_ES_01_P 
Job_168 Job_36  
Job_168 Job_30  
Job_169 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_45
Job_17  Job_5   Sjob_2
Job_170 Job_169 
Job_171 Job_Tealium_AS_01_P 
Job_172 Job_171 
Job_172 Job_168 
Job_173 Job_172 
Job_173 Job_37  
Job_174 Job_168 
Job_174 Job_173 
Job_175 Job_174 
Job_175 Job_44  
Job_175 Job_34  
Job_175 Job_173 
Job_176 Job_117 
Job_176 Job_115 
Job_177 Job_176 
Job_178 Job_88  
Job_178 Job_115 
Job_178 Job_116 
Job_179 Job_178 
Job_18  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_20
Job_180 Job_179 
Job_181 Job_164 
Job_181 Job_88  
Job_181 Job_91  
Job_181 Job_115 
Job_181 Job_116 
Job_182 Job_181 
Job_183 Job_182 
Job_184 Job_174 
Job_184 Job_75  
Job_185 Job_184 
Job_185 Job_44  
Job_186 Job_174 
Job_186 Job_35  
Job_187 Job_75  
Job_188 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_46
Job_189 Job_188 
Job_19  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_15
Job_190 Job_187 
Job_190 Job_105 
Job_190 Job_189 
Job_190 Job_34  
Job_190 Job_36  
Job_190 Job_64  
Job_190 Job_66  
Job_191 Job_185 
Job_191 Job_64  
Job_192 Job_174 
Job_192 Job_64  
Job_192 Job_175 
Job_193 Job_191 
Job_193 Job_192 
Job_193 Job_171 
Job_193 Job_175 
Job_197 Job_44  
Job_197 Job_115 
Job_197 Job_118 
BIL_Job_198 Job_5   Sjob_48
Job_199 Job_198 
Job_20  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_16
Job_200 Job_5   Sjob_47
Job_201 Job_200 
Job_207     
Job_208     
Job_209     
Job_21  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_19
Job_210     
Job_211 Job_171 
Job_211 Job_207 
Job_211 Job_208 
Job_211 Job_209 
Job_211 Job_210 
Job_212 Job_211 
Job_212 Job_207 
Job_213 Job_211 
Job_213 Job_208 
Job_214 Job_211 
Job_214 Job_209 
Job_215 Job_211 
Job_215 Job_210 
Job_216 Job_36  
Job_216 Job_35  
Job_217 Job_81  
Job_217 Job_118 
Job_218 Job_81  
Job_218 Job_118 
Job_219 Job_118 
Job_219 Job_119 
Job_219 Job_36  
Job_219 Job_35  
Job_219 Job_34  
Job_22  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_17
Job_220 Job_118 
Job_220 Job_44  
Job_221 Job_217 
Job_221 Job_218 
Job_221 Job_219 
Job_221 Job_220 
Job_221 Job_115 
Job_221 Job_164 
Job_222 Job_261 
Job_222 Job_37  
Job_222 Job_171 
Job_222 Job_239 
Job_222 Job_527 
Job_223 Job_164 
Job_224 Job_164 
Job_225 Job_164 
Job_226 Job_164 
Job_227 Job_216 
Job_228 Job_221 
Job_229 Job_222 
Job_23  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_18
Job_230 Job_223 
Job_231 Job_224 
Job_231 Job_233 
Job_232 Job_225 
Job_232 Job_230 
Job_233 Job_226 
Job_233 Job_232 
Job_234 Job_186 
Job_235 Job_193 
Job_236 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_49
Job_237 Job_236 
Job_237 Job_37  
Job_238     
Job_239 Job_212 
BIL_Job_24  Job_1   
Job_240     
Job_241 Job_240 
Job_242 Job_241 Job_240
Job_243 Job_199 
Job_244     
Job_245 Job_244 
Job_246 Job_245 Job_243
Job_247     
Job_248 Job_247 
Job_249 Job_248 
Job_25  Job_5   Sjob_21
Job_250     
Job_251 Job_250 
Job_252 Job_251 
Job_253     
Job_254 Job_253 
Job_255 Job_254 
Job_256 Job_254 Job_253
Job_26  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_13
Job_260 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_50
Job_262 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_2
Job_263 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_8
Job_264 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_1
Job_265 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_16
Job_267 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_11
Job_268 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_14
Job_269 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_21
Job_27  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_12
Job_270 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_18
Job_271 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_19
Job_272 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_15
Job_273 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_22
Job_275 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_21
Job_276 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_3
Job_277 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_4
Job_279 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_23
Job_28  Job_5   Sjob_4
Job_281 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_7
Job_282 Job_238 Sjob_UCCE_2
Job_285 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_1
Job_286 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_2
Job_287 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_3
Job_288 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_4
Job_289 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_5
Job_29  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_14
Job_290 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_6
Job_291 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_7
Job_292 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_8
Job_293 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_9
Job_294 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_26
Job_295 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_27
Job_296 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_28
Job_298 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_30
Job_299 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_10
Job_30  Job_29  
Job_300 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_35
Job_301 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_12
Job_302 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_13
Job_303 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_14
Job_304 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_15
Job_305 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_16
Job_306 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_17
Job_307 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_19
Job_309 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_20
Job_31  Job_13  
Job_310 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_21
Job_312 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_31
Job_313 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_23
Job_314 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_24
Job_315 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_25
Job_316 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_32
Job_317 Job_416 Sjob_UWF_1
Job_318 Job_420 Sjob_SRVN_1
Job_319 Job_263 
Job_319 Job_264 
Job_32  Job_9   
Job_321     
Job_323     
Job_325     
Job_326     
Job_33  Job_11  
Job_330     
Job_331     
Job_332     
Job_333     
Job_334 Job_267 
Job_334 Job_281 
Job_335 Job_332 
Job_336 Job_333 
Job_337 Job_277 
Job_338 Job_268 
Job_338 Job_319 
Job_338 Job_344 
Job_338 Job_352 
Job_339     
Job_34  Job_8   
Job_34  Job_10  
Job_34  Job_373 
Job_340 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_33
Job_341 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_34
Job_343 Job_301 
Job_344 Job_282 
Job_345 Job_300 
Job_346 Job_306 
Job_347 Job_285 
Job_348 Job_286 
Job_348 Job_352 
Job_348 Job_347 
Job_348 Job_343 
Job_348 Job_302 
Job_349 Job_272 
Job_349 Job_273 
Job_349 Job_279 
Job_349 Job_317 
Job_35  Job_26  
Job_35  Job_36  
Job_352 Job_289 
Job_352 Job_290 
Job_352 Job_299 
Job_352 Job_301 
Job_352 Job_303 
Job_352 Job_304 
Job_352 Job_340 
Job_352 Job_310 
Job_352 Job_312 
Job_352 Job_313 
Job_352 Job_314 
Job_352 Job_341 
Job_352 Job_315 
Job_352 Job_288 
Job_353 Job_330 
Job_354 Job_262 
Job_354 Job_319 
Job_354 Job_344 
Job_354 Job_352 
Job_355 Job_272 
Job_355 Job_319 
Job_355 Job_334 
Job_355 Job_337 
Job_355 Job_349 
Job_355 Job_451 
Job_355 Job_352 
Job_356 Job_265 
Job_356 Job_319 
Job_356 Job_352 
Job_357 Job_269 
Job_357 Job_319 
Job_357 Job_334 
Job_357 Job_352 
Job_358 Job_270 
Job_358 Job_337 
Job_359 Job_292 
Job_359 Job_309 
Job_359 Job_346 
Job_359 Job_293 
Job_359 Job_345 
Job_36  Job_27  
Job_360 Job_271 
Job_360 Job_337 
Job_360 Job_334 
Job_362 Job_275 
Job_362 Job_334 
Job_363 Job_273 
Job_365 Job_318 
Job_365 Job_349 
Job_365 Job_319 
Job_365 Job_352 
Job_365 Job_419 
Job_366 Job_317 
Job_366 Job_319 
Job_366 Job_349 
Job_366 Job_367 
Job_366 Job_399 
Job_366 Job_352 
Job_367 Job_317 
Job_368 Job_286 
Job_368 Job_352 
Job_368 Job_347 
Job_368 Job_343 
Job_368 Job_302 
Job_368 Job_287 
Job_369 Job_305 
Job_369 Job_352 
Job_369 Job_347 
Job_369 Job_343 
Job_369 Job_302 
Job_369 Job_307 
Job_37  Job_260 
Job_370 Job_288 
Job_370 Job_341 
Job_370 Job_340 
Job_371 Job_298 
Job_372 Job_295 
Job_372 Job_296 
Job_372 Job_435 
Job_372 Job_436 
Job_372 Job_438 
Job_372 Job_371 
Job_372 Job_430 
Job_372 Job_352 
Job_372 Job_349 
Job_373 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_53
Job_374 Job_375 
Job_374 Job_376 
Job_374 Job_378 
Job_375 Job_400 
Job_376 Job_400 
Job_378 Job_400 
Job_379 Job_378 
Job_379 Job_375 
Job_379 Job_376 
Job_379 Job_374 
Job_38  Job_17  
Job_380 Job_326 
Job_381 Job_380 
Job_382 Job_325 
Job_383 Job_382 
Job_384 Job_321 
Job_386 Job_323 
Job_387 Job_413 
Job_388 Job_387 
Job_389 Job_386 
Job_39  Job_28  
Job_390 Job_407 
Job_391 Job_390 
Job_392 Job_339 
Job_393 Job_331 
Job_394 Job_393 
Job_395 Job_398 
Job_396 Job_335 
Job_397 Job_336 
Job_398 Job_392 
Job_398 Job_396 
Job_398 Job_381 
Job_398 Job_391 
Job_398 Job_352 
Job_398 Job_441 
Job_398 Job_349 
Job_398 Job_37  
Job_399 Job_317 
Job_40  Job_20  
Job_40  Job_31  
Job_40  Job_32  
Job_40  Job_37  
Job_40  Job_34  
Job_400     
Job_407     
Job_41  Job_19  
Job_41  Job_31  
Job_41  Job_32  
Job_41  Job_37  
Job_413     
Job_415     
Job_416     
Job_417 Job_353 
Job_417 Job_391 
Job_417 Job_388 
Job_417 Job_383 
Job_417 Job_349 
Job_417 Job_381 
Job_417 Job_397 
Job_417 Job_389 
Job_417 Job_441 
Job_417 Job_394 
Job_417 Job_352 
Job_419 Job_318 
Job_42  Job_18  
Job_42  Job_37  
Job_42  Job_36  
Job_420     
Job_428 Job_399 
Job_428 Job_419 
Job_428 Job_346 
Job_428 Job_334 
Job_428 Job_397 
Job_428 Job_396 
Job_428 Job_438 
Job_428 Job_337 
Job_43  Job_22  
Job_43  Job_35  
Job_43  Job_36  
Job_43  Job_37  
Job_43  Job_34  
Job_43  Job_33  
Job_430 Job_294 
Job_431     
Job_432 Job_431 
Job_433 Job_317 
Job_433 Job_316 
Job_433 Job_352 
Job_433 Job_349 
Job_435 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_37
Job_436 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_38
Job_437 Job_415 Sjob_VRNT_39
Job_438 Job_437 
Job_439 Job_384 
Job_44  Job_24  
Job_440 Job_432 
Job_440 Job_439 
Job_441 Job_317 
Job_442     
Job_444 Job_5   Sjob_51
Job_445 Job_37  
Job_445 Job_444 
Job_446 Job_37  
Job_446 Job_171 
Job_446 Job_174 
Job_447 Job_446 
Job_448 Job_37  
Job_448 Job_171 
Job_448 Job_174 
Job_449 Job_448 
Job_45  Job_23  
Job_45  Job_30  
Job_45  Job_37  
Job_45  Job_34  
Job_45  Job_33  
Job_45  Job_35  
Job_45  Job_36  
Job_450 Job_433 
Job_450 Job_440 
Job_450 Job_417 
Job_450 Job_398 
Job_450 Job_372 
Job_450 Job_369 
Job_450 Job_368 
Job_450 Job_348 
Job_450 Job_366 
Job_450 Job_365 
Job_450 Job_363 
Job_450 Job_362 
Job_450 Job_360 
Job_450 Job_359 
Job_450 Job_358 
Job_450 Job_357 
Job_450 Job_356 
Job_450 Job_355 
Job_450 Job_354 
Job_450 Job_338 
Job_450 Job_379 
Job_450 Job_34  
Job_450 Job_64  
Job_451 Job_420 Sjob_SRVN_2
Job_452     
Job_453 Job_452 
Job_454 Job_453 
Job_454 Job_43  
Job_454 Job_74  
Job_454 Job_48  
Job_454 Job_467 
Job_455 Job_41  
Job_455 Job_459 
Job_456 Job_457 
Job_456 Job_458 
Job_456 Job_459 
Job_456 Job_455 
Job_457 Job_45  
Job_457 Job_74  
Job_458 Job_40  
Job_458 Job_32  
Job_459 Job_457 
Job_459 Job_458 
Job_459 Job_31  
Job_459 Job_36  
Job_459 Job_33  
Job_459 Job_30  
Job_46  Job_25  
Job_46  Job_30  
Job_46  Job_37  
Job_460 Job_16  
Job_461 Job_16  
Job_462 Job_50  
Job_463 Job_50  
Job_464 Job_50  
Job_465 Job_551 
Job_467 Job_453 
Job_468     
Job_469 Job_468 
Job_47  Job_21  
Job_47  Job_37  
Job_470 Job_469 
Job_471 Job_469 
Job_472 Job_470 
Job_472 Job_471 
Job_473 Job_472 
Job_474     
Job_475 Job_474 
Job_476 Job_475 
Job_477 Job_476 
Job_478 Job_477 
Job_479 Job_478 
Job_48  Job_7   
Job_48  Job_37  
Job_48  Job_34  
Job_480 Job_215 
Job_481 Job_480 
Job_482 Job_481 
Job_482 Job_214 
Job_482 Job_213 
Job_483 Job_481 
Job_483 Job_215 
Job_484 Job_45  
Job_484 Job_74  
Job_484 Job_482 
Job_484 Job_483 
Job_485     
Job_486 Job_485 
Job_487 Job_486 
Job_488 Job_576 
Job_489 Job_488 
Job_49  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_24
Job_490 Job_579 
Job_490 Job_43  
Job_491 Job_577 
Job_492 Job_488 
Job_493 Job_492 
Job_494 Job_416 Sjob_UWF_2
Job_495 Job_416 Sjob_UWF_3
Job_496 Job_416 Sjob_UWF_4
Job_497 Job_496 
Job_497 Job_495 
Job_497 Job_494 
Job_498 Job_488 
Job_499     
Job_5       
Job_50  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_26
Job_500 Job_488 
Job_501 Job_170 
Job_501 Job_110 
Job_501 Job_44  
Job_501 Job_45  
Job_501 Job_68  
Job_501 Job_74  
Job_501 Job_75  
Job_501 Job_48  
Job_501 Job_43  
Job_501 Job_42  
Job_501 Job_40  
Job_501 Job_189 
Job_501 Job_81  
Job_501 Job_71  
Job_502 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_54
Job_503 Job_502 
Job_503 Job_34  
Job_503 Job_37  
Job_504 Job_446 
Job_505 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_55
Job_506 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_56
Job_507 Job_505 
Job_507 Job_506 
Job_507 Job_37  
Job_508 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_57
Job_509 Job_508 
Job_509 Job_37  
Job_51  Job_5   Sjob_25
Job_510 Job_30  
Job_510 Job_32  
Job_510 Job_34  
Job_510 Job_36  
Job_510 Job_40  
Job_510 Job_41  
Job_510 Job_42  
Job_510 Job_43  
Job_510 Job_45  
Job_510 Job_56  
Job_510 Job_489 
Job_510 Job_490 
Job_510 Job_491 
Job_510 Job_531 
Job_510 Job_532 
Job_510 Job_556 
Job_510 Job_557 
Job_510 Job_558 
Job_510 Job_559 
Job_510 Job_560 
Job_510 Job_561 
Job_510 Job_562 
Job_510 Job_563 
Job_510 Job_564 
Job_510 Job_565 
Job_510 Job_566 
Job_510 Job_567 
Job_510 Job_568 
Job_510 Job_569 
Job_510 Job_570 
Job_510 Job_571 
Job_511 Job_56  
Job_511 Job_515 
Job_511 Job_514 
Job_511 Job_513 
Job_511 Job_112 
Job_512 Job_511 
Job_513 Job_56  
Job_513 Job_74  
Job_513 Job_33  
Job_513 Job_36  
Job_513 Job_34  
Job_513 Job_64  
Job_514 Job_509 
Job_515 Job_507 
Job_52  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_29
Job_525 Job_513 
Job_525 Job_43  
Job_526 Job_525 
Job_527 Job_212 
Job_528 Job_56  
Job_528 Job_71  
Job_528 Job_111 
Job_528 Job_112 
Job_528 Job_461 
Job_528 Job_488 
Job_528 Job_515 
Job_528 Job_514 
Job_528 Job_35  
Job_528 Job_36  
Job_528 Job_37  
Job_528 Job_74  
Job_528 Job_132 
Job_528 Job_460 
Job_528 Job_513 
Job_529     
Job_53  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_30
Job_530 Job_529 
Job_531 Job_578 
Job_531 Job_488 
Job_532 Job_488 
Job_533     
Job_534 Job_533 
Job_535 Job_534 
Job_536 Job_453 
Job_537 Job_453 
Job_538 Job_453 
Job_539 Job_454 
Job_539 Job_467 
Job_539 Job_536 
Job_539 Job_537 
Job_539 Job_538 
Job_54  Job_5   Sjob_27
Job_540 Job_530 
Job_541     
Job_542     
Job_543 Job_542 
Job_544     
Job_545 Job_544 
Job_546 Job_383 
Job_546 Job_352 
Job_546 Job_545 
Job_547     
Job_548 Job_74  
Job_548 Job_45  
Job_549 Job_215 
Job_549 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_58
Job_55  Job_5   Sjob_28
Job_550 Job_398 
Job_550 Job_391 
Job_550 Job_488 
Job_551     
Job_552 Job_171 
Job_553 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_61
Job_554 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_62
Job_555 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_63
Job_556 Job_488 
Job_556 Job_32  
Job_556 Job_40  
Job_556 Job_41  
Job_557 Job_488 
Job_557 Job_34  
Job_557 Job_36  
Job_557 Job_42  
Job_558 Job_488 
Job_558 Job_45  
Job_558 Job_36  
Job_559 Job_488 
Job_559 Job_580 
Job_56  Job_16  
Job_560 Job_488 
Job_560 Job_503 
Job_561 Job_488 
Job_562 Job_488 
Job_563 Job_488 
Job_564 Job_563 
Job_565 Job_45  
Job_565 Job_43  
Job_565 Job_491 
Job_565 Job_490 
Job_566 Job_488 
Job_566 Job_565 
Job_567 Job_488 
Job_567 Job_565 
Job_568 Job_488 
Job_568 Job_565 
Job_569 Job_488 
Job_569 Job_565 
Job_57  JOb_43  
Job_57  Job_45  
Job_570 Job_488 
Job_570 Job_491 
Job_570 Job_45  
Job_571 Job_488 
Job_572     
Job_573 Job_143 
Job_574 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_65
Job_575 Job_117 
Job_576 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_70
Job_577 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_71
Job_578 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_72
Job_579 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_73
Job_58  Job_48  
Job_580 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_74
Job_59  Job_42  
Job_60  Job_56  
Job_60  Job_57  
Job_60  Job_58  
Job_60  Job_59  
Job_60  Job_44  
Job_61  Job_57  
Job_61  Job_58  
Job_61  Job_59  
Job_61  Job_60  
Job_62  Job_61  
Job_63  Job_62  
Job_64  Job_49  
Job_65  Job_51  
Job_66  Job_50  
Job_67  Job_50  
Job_68  Job_30  
Job_68  Job_37  
Job_68  Job_34  
Job_68  Job_33  
Job_68  Job_35  
Job_68  Job_36  
Job_68  Job_464 
Job_68  Job_52  
Job_68  Job_74  
Job_69  Job_54  
Job_69  Job_36  
Job_69  Job_33  
Job_69  Job_464 
Job_7   Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_22
Job_70  Job_55  
Job_70  Job_36  
Job_70  Job_33  
Job_70  Job_464 
Job_71  Job_53  
Job_71  Job_36  
Job_71  Job_37  
Job_72  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_32
Job_73  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_31
Job_74  Job_30  
Job_74  Job_34  
Job_74  Job_33  
Job_74  Job_36  
Job_74  Job_35  
Job_74  Job_37  
Job_74  Job_72  
Job_74  Job_45  
Job_75  Job_30  
Job_75  Job_34  
Job_75  Job_33  
Job_75  Job_464 
Job_75  Job_36  
Job_75  Job_35  
Job_75  Job_37  
Job_75  Job_73  
Job_75  Job_68  
Job_76  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_34
Job_77  Job_76  
Job_78  Job_5   Sjob_33
Job_79  Job_78  
Job_8   Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_1
Job_80  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_36
Job_81  Job_33  
Job_81  Job_34  
Job_81  Job_30  
Job_81  Job_37  
Job_81  Job_80  
Job_82  Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_35
Job_83  Job_82  
Job_84  Job_5   Sjob_41
Job_85  Job_84  
Job_85  Job_36  
Job_86  Job_74  
Job_86  JOb_43  
Job_86  Job_36  
Job_87  Job_43  
Job_88  Job_86  
Job_89  Job_104 
Job_89  Job_105 
Job_89  Job_36  
Job_89  Job_66  
Job_89  Job_68  
Job_89  Job_96  
Job_89  Job_462 
Job_9   Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_5
Job_90  Job_86  
Job_91  Job_86  
Job_91  Job_90  
Job_92  Job_103 
Job_92  Job_89  
Job_93  Job_5   Sjob_42
Job_94  Job_5   Sjob_43
Job_95  Job_93  
Job_96  Job_462 
Job_96  Job_94  
Job_97  Job_98  
Job_98      
Job_99      
Job_Tealium_AS_01_P     
Job_Tealium_ES_01_P     
Job_581 Job_228 
Job_581 Job_230 
Job_581 Job_231 
Job_581 Job_232 
Job_581 Job_233 
Job_581 Job_235 
Job_581 Job_164 
Job_582 Job_398 
Job_582 Job_391 
Job_582 Job_396 
Job_582 Job_488 
Job_583 Job_571 
Job_583 Job_556 
Job_583 Job_560 
Job_583 Job_557 
Job_583 Job_558 
Job_583 Job_568 
Job_583 Job_561 
Job_583 Job_567 
Job_583 Job_566 
Job_583 Job_559 
Job_583 Job_570 
Job_583 Job_569 
Job_583 Job_564 
Job_583 Job_488 
Job_583 Job_56  
Job_583 Job_34  
Job_583 Job_45  
Job_583 Job_43  
Job_583 Job_30  
Job_583 Job_503 
Job_583 Job_42  
Job_583 Job_531 
Job_583 Job_40  
Job_583 Job_491 
Job_583 Job_490 
Job_583 Job_36  
Job_570 Job_74  
Job_565 Job_74  
Job_565 Job_56  
Job_TEST_AP     
Job_TEST_AF     
Job_320 Job_317 
Job_584 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_75
Job_585 Job_551 BDP2_Sjob_76
```

Comment: your sample data shows dependant job no and sub dependant job no that don't appear as job no rows; is this intentionally?  please show data that corresponds to your expected and actual results

Comment: Hi @ysth basically if you see my results.
JOB_41->JOB_19
JOB_19->JOB_551 AND JOB_19->BDP2_SJOB_15
So basically this means job_19 is dependant upon 2 jobs that is JOB_551 and BDP2_SJOB_15.
But the recursion has happened only for JOB_551 and not subjobs for JOB_19.
I need the results like
`JOB_41->JOB_19
  JOB_19->JOB_551->BDP2_SJOB_15
 JOB_551->XX -XX
BDP2_SJOB_15 ->XX->XX
xx  - xx -xx  of JOB_551 Child
xx- xx -xx of  bdp2_sjob_15 `

Comment: Hi @ysth I have attached the dataset for your reference.
In simple words i need to list of all the dependant_job_no and subdependant_job_no of 
the parent_job recursively.

Comment: Hi @ysth Just for your info 
The job BDP2_SJOB_15 has a typo and is termed as Job_15..
I have used replace function..

Comment: See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055). #5 - provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. #3 - provide complete (not "should look like"!!!) desired output for shown sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt recursively adds rows based on DEPENDANT_JOB_NO and recursively adds rows based on DEPENDANT_SUB_JOB_NO, but that isn't finding dependent sub jobs used by dependent jobs or dependent jobs used by dependent sub jobs.  To do this, use a single recursive cte with two unions:

```
with recursive rec_cte as (
    select JOB_NO,DEPENDANT_JOB_NO,DEPENDANT_SUB_JOB_NO
    from CTL_TALEND_JOBS_METADATA 
    where JOB_NO ='Job_198'

    union all

    select p.DEPENDANT_JOB_NO,h.DEPENDANT_JOB_NO,h.DEPENDANT_SUB_JOB_NO
    from rec_cte p
    inner join CTL_TALEND_JOBS_METADATA h
        on (h.JOB_NO = p.DEPENDANT_JOB_NO)

    union all

    select p.DEPENDANT_SUB_JOB_NO,h.DEPENDANT_JOB_NO,h.DEPENDANT_SUB_JOB_NO
    from rec_cte p
    inner join CTL_TALEND_JOBS_METADATA h
        on (h.JOB_NO = REPLACE(p.DEPENDANT_SUB_JOB_NO,'BDP2_Sj','J'))
)
select * from rec_cte
```